# Dynamic controls not rendering in WinForm

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, controls

I'm trying to create a list of labels and textboxes. No errors but they aren't rendering on the form. I have confirmed my loop have values

```
Private Sub AddLabels_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'MsgBox(strNumberOfLabels + " " + strOrderNum)
    TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = True
    TableLayoutPanel1.Visible = False
    TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
    For i As Integer = 0 To strNumberOfLabels

        'MsgBox(i)
        Dim txtBox As New TextBox
        Dim txtLabel As New Label
        txtLabel.Text = "Label " + i
        txtBox.Name = "txt" + i
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtLabel)
        txtLabel.Show()
        txtBox.Show()
        TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()
        TableLayoutPanel1.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the other `Add` overload, which specifies which column and row the control should go into:

```
Dim txtLabel As New Label
txtLabel.Text = "Label" + i.ToString
'\\ TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtLabel)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtLabel, 0, 0)
```

This is not necessary:

```
'\\ txtLabel.Show()
```

This should be moved outside of the loop:

```
  Next
TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()
'\\ TableLayoutPanel1.Visible = True
```

The `txtBox` control is never being added to the `TableLayoutPanel` control or the form.

I don't think it's necessary to make your TableLayoutPanel visible or invisible during the `OnLoad` procedure, the form isn't visible yet.

The only other thing to confirm is the value of `strNumberOfLabels`.  I'm suspecting it's zero.

Comment: Not yet but those last two certainly werent going to work in the loop

Comment: @Somejerk Other than my notes, I am not able to reproduce the problem.  I have a label going into a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: I took out the for loop and it still did it plus I confirmed values with the msgboxs. Very odd.

Comment: I added .ToSteing on int i and viola! Thanks for your help!